# Render a mixin Pug template

Tags: node.js, pug, template-engine

I want to render a template after a Ajax call.

My code is:

```
index.pug
  include form.pug
  +list('style')

form.pug
mixin list(style)
   p(class=style) my form
```

I want to add form.pug after click a button, so

my ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/myroute",
        method: "POST",
        data: msgObj,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            div.prepend(msg.template)
        },
    });
```

/myroute (server-node) is:

```
const pug = require('pug');
var template = pug.renderFile('Path/form.pug');
res.send({"template":template,"style":"new_style"});
```

My template doesn't appear after click the button.
In I remove mixin, everything works, but I need pass a param during the template generation

Answer (score 0):

Call the mixin somewhere in the page, select it in the DOM after AJAX call and fill the needed values before prepending it.